# How to create something like a textual "add other term" for taxonomy terms?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 7

How can I setup taxonomy terms so that you can have an extra field called "others", where you can add your own terms if the term you want to use is not defined yet as a term of that taxonomy?

I have researched and came across a module called [Select(or other)](https://www.drupal.org/node/1158654). It does what I want, but it is in text.

My problem now is that I've added so much taxonomies for my student record content type (like countries, or faculties). So I've gone too far and cannot cancel (undo) the taxonomies and replace them with the module I found.

Any suggestion of how to add something like such extra field to the existing taxonomy module?

I imagine that when users insert data, they might not find appropriate terms to choose from. So I want to give them an option that "if current term don't apply to you, then please insert your term manually".

I'm still newbie in Drupal7 and PHP programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider something that looks like this "Type of Fruit" taxonomy (with 'Banana' and 'Pear' as the only existing terms):

[image: Sample UI for proposed widget]

Obviously, the [Select (or other)](https://www.drupal.org/project/select_or_other) module that you mentioned is for select lists, you cannot use it for taxonomies. However, to somehow address your requirement like "... insert term here ...", you might want to consider using "Widget type" = "Autocomplete term widget (tagging)" when you actually define the Term reference field.

To further enhance the experience of your users, you may want to also consider the [Autocomplete Deluxe](https://www.drupal.org/project/autocomplete_deluxe) module or the [Chosen](https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen) module (for better UI and functionality).

Comment: Oh very nice idea..i always thought that tagging will get the user to guess what are the option available. but never knew it could do that!
i think I'll use the the Field Description to tell the user what the the options available, so that he doesn't create a (dum term) by himself, otherwise, i would be a mess.
i think the solution to my problem is perfectly addressed. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

When you go to your Taxonomy Vocabulary (`[your_domain]/admin/structure/taxonomy/your_vocabulary`) you can click on `Manage Fields` tab and add any field you want. Or go to `[your_domain]/admin/structure/taxonomy/your_vocabulary/fields`.

Comment: will that make the user add new filed by himself in content type?
i mean i dont expect the users to have any access other than the content type when inserting data.